# How can I get a Bootstrap based menu bar to match the color of current slider image on WP?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I was wondering if someone could advise me on what I might want to do in a particular situation.  I have a client who asked fro a Twitter Bootstrap based WordPress theme.  The theme has a slider carousel on the front page.  One slide has a green background, another orange, and another red.  The client showed me a site where the slider ran right up next to the top navigation bar.  When the current slide is the one with the green background, the top navigation bar is green to match... and similarly with Orange and Red.  So, when the slide changes to the image that has a background of orange the top navigation bar changes to have that same colored background.

I tried to use CSS3 animations to sync with the slider by setting the animation to change after 5 seconds, just as the slider was changing every 5 seconds.  The results were not so great.  I guess the problem is that the CSS3 color animation doesn't change directly from one color to another but animates the transition, going through various intermediate colors during the transition.

Putting the navbar inside the carousel didn't seem to work.  I was hoping that this would help me to synchronize the navbar background color styling with the slider, applying a new style class that could be targeted by CSS to change the navbar background.  This was not a good solution at all.  Depending on where I placed the navbar code, it might not show up at all or definitely in the wrong place.

So, perhaps with JQuery I could find out what slide is currently showing and use that to change the class on the navbar to display a different navbar background.  Or I could just use a timer that adds different classes at different times and then use that to change the color of the navbar background at different times, e.g. every 5 seconds.
Thanks in advance for any help,
Bruce

Comment: Please provide some of the code you are using.

Comment: Make the navbar transparent and put the slider behind it, add padding (the height of the navbar) to the top of the slider to provide space for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier to place the navbar on top of the slider then make the navbar transparent and change the css on the links inside the navbar.

[image]

## DEMO: http://jsbin.com/wevini/1/

### HTML

```
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
  <body>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-transparent navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Carousel
    ================================================== -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active item-1">

          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-2">

          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
              <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-3">

          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->



    <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

    <div class="container marketing">

      <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      </div><!-- /.row -->


      <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

      <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It'll blow your mind.</span></h2>
          <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it's that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
          <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
          <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->


      <!-- FOOTER -->
      <footer>
        <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
        <p>&copy; 2014 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
      </footer>

    </div><!-- /.container -->
```

### CSS

```
/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}


@media (min-width:768px) { 
    .navbar-transparent {
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .navbar-transparent .nav.navbar-nav > li > a {
        color: #fff
    }
    .navbar-transparent .nav.navbar-nav li.active > a {
        background: transparent
    }
    .navbar-transparent .navbar-brand {
        color: #fff
    }
}
.item-1 {
    background: red
}
.item-2 {
    background: purple
}
.item-3 {
    background: blue
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}

/* Flip around the padding for proper display in narrow viewports */
.navbar-wrapper > .container {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}



/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}


/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}



/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  /* Navbar positioning foo */
  .navbar-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* The navbar becomes detached from the top, so we round the corners */
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
}
```